# Create backups of currently running outlook express .ost file

Tags: backup, outlook

I am using Outlook Express 2007. I have configured it with Exchange Server and have .ost file.

I want to create a backup of this OST/PST file without closing Outlook Express.

What tool can I use to create a backup of the .ost file without closing outlook express?

Comment: One way to possibly go about this is to hibernate your computer, load into a different OS (for example, Ubuntu), and then create a copy of the file from there.

Comment: You should look into any program that uses the "shadow copy service" to read open files. There are many questions within the site asking for that feature in particular.

Comment: Note that you don't need to back up OST files as these are internal Outlook caches that will be of absolutely zero use if/when you need to be restoring from the backup. But as Mawg answered below the keyword you are looking for is "shadow copying" - that's a built-in Windows framework that exists *exactly* for copying files that are in active use.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many free backup solutions, and recommended several here, but after another recent round of comparison, I have happily spent US $19.99 to purchase [bvckup2](https://www.bvckup2.com/).

I bought it primarily for its speed, since I have large amounts of data. I particularly like how it only copies changes.

But what interests you is

> Backup of locked files
>
> Use Windows shadow copying to backup files that
> are locked for exclusive use by running programs such as web browsers
> or email clients.

There is a 2 week fully functional free trial, and you can also download the last beta (forever), but it is well worth the $19.99. Visit the website and read all of the features.

[Update] I recently had cause to purchase tow more licenses, wrote to Alex, the author & he gave me a 20% discount code. Yesterday evening, one license stopped working as I had swapped motherboards and added a few new drives to my server, thus giving a different "hardware fingerprint" and invalidating the license. I emailed him and got an answer within 2 or 43 minutes, which is typical of his response time on support (if his time zone is awake when mine is).

A great product, with great support, which does exactly what the question asks for - and oh so very much much more..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you're using Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 (not Outlook Express). There is a **free** tool that can create backups easily (having Outlook open): [Backup Outlook Items](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderBackup/).

Please note that I'm one of the developers. The software is fully compatible with Outlook 2007-2016 (including Office 365 and x64 editions). Free version is for home non-commercial use only. Commercial version provides more options.